# All rows where at least one child has all of its own children pass a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a little trouble with a SQL query, and thought I'd solicit the wisdom of the crowd to see what I'm missing. I'm pretty sure the below works, but it seems really poor and I'm wondering if there's a smarter way (ideally using joins instead of sub-selects) to do this.

**The Problem**

Let's say I have some tables:

```
Prize
  - PrizeId

RulePrize_Map
  - PrizeId
  - RuleId

Rule
  - RuleId

Conditional
  - ConditionalId
  - RuleId
  - InputId
  - ExpectedValue (bit)

Input
  - InputId
```

A `Prize` is won when at least one `Rule` is true. A `Rule` is true when *all* of its `Conditionals` are true. A `Conditional` is "true" when its `InputId` is either present or not present in the `Input` table, as designated by the `ExpectedValue` field. This could perhaps be treated as equivalent to: `Count(InputId in Input table)` = `ExpectedValue` for the `Conditional's` `InputId`.

Some Examples:

```
Conditional (InputId = 11, ExpectedValue = 1) -> True if InputId 11 in Input Table
Conditional (InputId = 12, ExpectedValue = 0) -> True if Inputid 12 NOT in Input Table
```

**My Goal**

I want to get all `Prizes` where at least one `Rule` is "true". I would settle for: "All `Rules` that are true".

**My Attempt**

```
select p.PrizeId from Prize p INNER JOIN RulePrize_Map rpm ON rpm.PrizeId = p.PrizeId
WHERE p.PrizeId IN
(select r.PrizeId from Rule r
where
  (select count(*) from Conditional c1 where c1.RuleId = r.RuleId)
  = 
  (select count(*) from Conditional c2
   where c2.RuleId = r.RuleId AND
   (select count(*) from Input i where i.InputId = c2.InputId) = c2.ExpectedValue
  )
)
GROUP BY p.prizeId
```

Comment: Just an idea: maybe looking at excluding Prizes where all rules are false...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question change a bit, so I have redone the answer...

```
SELECT
  PrizeId
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    PrizeRule_Map.PrizeId,
    PrizeRule_Map.RuleId
  FROM
    PrizeRule_Map
  INNER JOIN
    Rule
      ON Rule.RuleId = PrizeRule_Map.RuleId
  INNER JOIN
    Conditional
      ON Conditional.RuleId = Rule.RuleID
  LEFT JOIN
    Input
      ON Input.InputId = Conditional.InputID
  GROUP BY
    PrizeRule_Map.PrizeId,
    PrizeRule_Map.RuleId
  HAVING
    COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE Conditional.ExpectedValue
                     WHEN 1 THEN CASE WHEN Input.InputId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                     WHEN 0 THEN CASE WHEN Input.InputId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                   END
                   )
  )
    AS map
GROUP BY
  PrizeId
```

Comment: This does "where any rule is true".  If you want "where all rules are true", then remove the "PrizeRule_Map.RuleId" lines from the SELECT and GROUP BY of the main query (and then you don't need the wrapper query either).

Comment: Many thanks for the "Prize" update as per the question change.

Comment: @Dems: `LEFT JOIN ON Input.InputId = ...`, you miss `Input`

Comment: @ypercube: nah, that was intentional, I wanted to see if the OP would notice. Honest.  *blush*

Comment: @Dems - lol I did, but didn't want to be a stickler with an otherwise perfect answer

Answer (score 1):

To get all `RuleId`s where ALL Conditionals are true:

```
SELECT r.RuleID
FROM Rule r
  JOIN Conditional c
    ON c.RuleId = r.RuleId
  LEFT JOIN Input i
    ON i.InputId = c.InputId
GROUP BY r.RuleID
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN (c.ExpectedValue=1) AND (i.InputId IS NOT NULL)
                     OR (c.ExpectedValue=0) AND (i.InputId IS NULL)
                   THEN 1
                   ELSE NULL 
              END ) 
       = COUNT( * )
```

Another way - probably slower but it doesn't hurt to test for speed. It doesn't use `CASE` but the difference (`EXCEPT`) of two `JOIN`s, only one of them using `GROUP BY`:

```
    SELECT r.RuleID
    FROM Rule r
      JOIN Conditional c
        ON c.RuleId = r.RuleId
      LEFT JOIN Input i
        ON i.InputId = c.InputId
    WHERE c.ExpectedValue = 1
    GROUP BY r.RuleID
    HAVING COUNT( i.InputId ) = COUNT( * )
  EXCEPT
    SELECT r.RuleID
    FROM Rule r
      JOIN Conditional c
        ON c.RuleId = r.RuleId
      JOIN Input i
        ON i.InputId = c.InputId
    WHERE c.ExpectedValue = 0
```

Comment: You used `COUNT(NULL|1)` where I used `SUM(0|1)`, are you aware of any performance differences for this?

Comment: Need to specify `i.InputId` or `c.InputId` in the boolean logic?

Comment: Quite a clever option second. I like the `Count` method for clarity as well.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
SELECT Rule.RuleId, Rule.RuleName
FROM Rule
INNER JOIN Conditional ON Rule.RuleId = Conditional.RuleId
Where Conditional.ExpectedValue == true
```

Comment: Your query does not consider "all" conditionals associated with the rule, and does not even look at the contents of `Input`.

Comment: That would show all Rules where only one condition is true. It also doesn't evaluate Conditional's properly (ExpectedValue == true doesn't make the Conditional true necessarily, instead it indicates the Conditional is true if the Input table contains the Conditional's InputId).

Comment: This doesn't handle expectedVluae = false and there being a value on the Input Table

Comment: @pascal, @Graphain and @Jon Egerton. The question has been modified. The goal is different now. My answer is for the previous goal i.e "I want to get all Rules where all of their Conditionals are "true"."

Comment: Read the original question, the Conditions are "true" was defined as "The count of inputs = the ExpectedValue in conditional"